# Building ParaView-Superbuild in windows 10

Tags: cmake, cygwin, paraview

I'm trying to build the ParaView-Superbuild (https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild) on Windows 10 64x.

I cannot manage to get it to work. I just ran from error to error. Currently I'm stuck at:

```
CMake Error at superbuild/projects/win32/boost.cmake:5 (message):
At least Visual Studio 9.0 is required
Call Stack (most recent call first):
superbuild/cmake/SuperbuildMacros.cmake:690 (include)
superbuild/CMakeLists.txt:145 (_superbuild_discover_projects)
```

using Cmake 3.13.10-rc1 as generator for Ninja. I have Cygwin64 installed and I'm using the GCC compiler

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0  
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
```

Since I thought that the error has something to do with the compiler I tried to switch to the installed VS2017 compiler. However, the build process will then crash with

```
  CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules
  /CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler
  "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools               
  /MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.
  It fails with the following output:
  Change Dir: C:/paraview-superbuild/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
  Run Build Command:"C:/Ninja/ninja.exe" "cmTC_915a7"
  [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_915a7.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
  [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_915a7.exe
  FAILED: cmTC_915a7.exe 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe  
  --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_915a7.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1
  \2017\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1415~1.267\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo 
  CMakeFiles\cmTC_915a7.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_915a7.exe 
  /implib:cmTC_915a7.lib /pdb:cmTC_915a7.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64  
  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib  
  winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib 
  advapi32.lib && cd ."
  RC Pass 1: command "rc /foCMakeFiles\cmTC_915a7.dir/manifest.res 
  CMakeFiles\cmTC_915a7.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the 
  following output:
  The system cannot find the file specified
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (
```

I don't know how to fix the error using the GCC compiler when the VS one is not working at all. Sadly, I couldn't find any help on the Paraview website.

Has somebody managed to build it and can show me step by step how to do it?

And no, I don't want to use Linux here.

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to build as cygwin or as windows  program ?

Comment: Since cygwin is running under windows. It's the same in both cases.

Comment: It is not the same. For cygwin you need to use the cygwin gcc. Visual studio will only produce a Windows program. The message `CMake Error at superbuild/projects/win32/boost.cmake:5 (message):` means that or you or upstream are defaulting to a pure windows build.

Comment: t thought the cygwin compiler will produce a window program as well since alle the toolts provided are made to run under windows?
Okay, but then again I cannot get it to work with the VS compiler.
However, I did manage to build it using not the superbuild but the "normal" source files provided here: https://www.paraview.org/download/

Comment: afaik, ParaView does not support officialy cygwyn. I would suggest VS2015 + Ninja for a reliable build process.

Comment: Okay, but like mentioned in my post the it will give me errors when I try to Ninja and VS. does not work. I even tried with VS 15 and VS 17.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reliable way to build ParaView Superbuild on windows

- Install Visual Studio 2013 community with all C++ related tools
- Install cmake
- Install git bash
- Install Ninja
- Install Qt 5.9.2 VS2013
- Install other potential dependencies
- open git bash

then :

```
 cd C:/
 mkdir pv
 cd pv
 git clone git@gitlab.kitware.com:paraview/paraview-superbuild.git
 mv paraview-superbuild pvsb
 mkdir pvsb_b
 cd pvsb
 git submodule update --init --recursive
```

- Open Visual Studio Native Command X64

then :

```
cd C:\pv\pvsb_b
cmake-gui
```

- configure paraview-superbuild accordingly to your need
- ENABLE_qt5 and USE_SYSTEM_qt should be ON
- generate
- close cmake-gui

`ninja`